# Find the integral solutions of $x^4+y^4+z^4-w^4=1995$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was not able to understand how to proceed. I tried with factorisation 1995. But couldn't understand how to show that $x^4+y^4+z^4-w^4$ has not factors.

Comment: This doesn't seem very elementary. As a data point, Wolfram isn't capable of finding any integer points.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $x^4$ (mod $16$) is always equal to $0$ or $1$.  So adding three fourth powers together and subtracting a fourth must yield a result that is in $\{0,1,2,3,15\}$ (mod $16$).  Since $1995 \equiv 11$ (mod $16$), there are no integer solutions to this equation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to factorize anything. You just note that the fourth root of 1995 is between 6 and 7, so you only need to look at numbers not exceeding 6.  since $4^4 = 256,$ you must have either exactly one $6$ or two $5$s. The rest is pretty simple.

**EDIT** Did not notice the minus sign...

So, consider the equation mod 5. The right hand side is zero. $a^4 \equiv 1 \mod 5$ for any $a$ relatively prime to 5. So, simple arithmetic tells us that (wlog) $x, y \equiv 0 \mod 5.$ That's where the enlightenment ends...

Comment: If the condition were $x^4+y^4+z^4+w^4=1995$ I'd agree, but the presence of the minus sign on $w^4$ seems like it renders this insufficient.

Comment: @Semiclassical Oops. Reading comprehension issues...